# What is the penalty for lying about a face-down card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say someone deliberately casts a sorcery card as a face-down morph creature hoping to win the game with it (not knowing that at some point in time it will always be revealed). What is the penalty for it at the different Rules Enforcement Levels (REL)?

Comment: In your situation, is the judge able to determine that the cheating was deliberate?

Comment: @Rainbolt good question. My initial thought was that the cheater admits what he did so the accepted answer is all what I asked. But reading the discussion it is of course also interesting what would happen if somebody cheats but denies it and it isn't clear whether it was deliberate but I personally think that should be a new question.

Comment: This happened to me once on a PTQ. 

I Had Polukranos and a Sagu Mauler on my Hand.

I am I went, pay 3 morph creature. I Placed the Polukranos face down.

Never realized it was the wrong card. After the game finished, I told my my oponent and the judge what happened, and since it was a mistake I was given a Game Loss instead of a DQ.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Cheating is not tolerated at any REL and must always result in disqualification.**

The current Rules Enforcement Levels (REL) are *Regular*, *Competitive*, and *Professional*.

The [Tournament rules](http://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_22jan16_en.pdf) state about cheating:

> **5.1 Cheating**
>
> Cheating will not be tolerated. The Head Judge reviews all cheating allegations, and if he or she believes that a player has cheated, he or she will issue the appropriate penalty based on the Infraction Procedure Guide or Judging at Regular REL document. All disqualifications are subject to DCI review and further penalties may be assessed.

The rules for [Judging at Regular REL](https://www.wizards.com/ContentResources/Wizards/WPN/Main/Documents/Magic_The_Gathering_Judging_at_Regular_REL_PDF1.pdf) state:

> **Serious Problems**
>
> Certain actions will not be tolerated under any circumstances. Every effort should be made to educate players before and during events; however, ignorance is not an acceptable defence of these actions. Any player engaging in the following must be removed from your event and, at the Organizer's discretion, removed from the venue entirely:
>
> - Aggressive, violent or abusive behavior (physical or verbal).
> - **Intentionally and knowingly breaking or letting an opponent break game or tournament rules, or lying.** (“Bluffing” about cards opponents can't normally see is permitted).
> - Determining match outcomes by incentives, coercion, or outside-the-game methods, or gambling on any part of a tournament.
> - Theft (including things like replacing a card in a draft with one from a player’s binder).
>
> Removing players in this way is called a Disqualification, and we must always try to educate our players on why these actions are unacceptable. Also let the player know that while your decision is final, the Judge Program would still like to hear his or her side of the story. You can contact your local Regional Coordinator, high level Judge, or WPN Representative to guide you through the process of a Disqualification.

The [Infraction Procedure Guide](https://www.wizards.com/ContentResources/Wizards/WPN/Main/Documents/Magic_The_Gathering_Infraction_Procedure_Guide_PDF2.pdf) is used for penalties at Competitive and Professional REL and states:

> **4.8. Unsporting Conduct — Cheating**
>
> **Definition**
>
> A person breaks a rule defined by the tournament documents, lies to a tournament official, or notices an offense committed in his or her (or a teammate's) match and does not call attention to it.
>
> Additionally, the offense must meet the following criteria for it to be considered Cheating:
>
> - The player must be attempting to gain advantage from his or her action.
> - The player must be aware that he or she is doing something illegal.
>
> If all criteria are not met, the offense is not Cheating and should be handled by a different infraction. Cheating will often appear on the surface as a Game Play Error or Tournament Error, and must be investigated by the judge to make a determination of intent and awareness.
>
> **Penalty:** Disqualification

Comment: This address the case where it is done **intentionally**. Since there could be cases where it is unclear whether it was done intentionally, it could be useful to include any rules specifying what will happen if it was done unintentionally.

Comment: This answer could be improved by noting that this applies to REL Regular and above, and you could talk about how the IPG recommends handling it at lower REL

Comment: @kasperd OP specifically asked about "deliberately" violating the rules. That is known as cheating.

Comment: @Hackworth Only the person who did it knows if it was done deliberately or not. When in doubt the organizer might assume it was done unintentionally.

Comment: @Daenyth Regular REL is the lowest REL, with COmpetitive and Professional above it, and I did write that cheating is met with disqualification at any REL.

Comment: @Hackworth: I think either I'm misremembering or it's changed; I thought prereleases were at a lower REL still than FNM's Regular. Carry on

Comment: @kasperd That is wrong, or rather, irrelevant. The Head Judge is the final authority on what happened. If - after investigating - he or she decides it was intentional, then it was intentional, and will be punished accordingly. Again, the question was about cases when it was decided to be intentional.

Comment: @Daenyth These are the current tournament rules, see page 9 for REL definitions: http://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_22jan16_en.pdf

Comment: @Hackworth: I see, it appears the RELs have changed; there used to be 5 levels (c ~2010). http://www.wizards.com/dci/judge/main.asp?x=judge/MTG_DCI_Judge_Penalty

Comment: @Hackworth The question is not as specific as you assert. You are making assumptions about what the OP had in mind when asking the question.

Comment: @kasperd OP asked about a "deliberate" rules violation and "lying" about a face-down card. How much more obvious does it have to get whether or not the question is about cheating rather than accidental misplays? I suggest you google the dictionary definitions of "deliberate" and "to lie", if that's not clear.

Comment: @Hackworth You said the question is about a scenario where an official has decided it was done deliberately. I don't see the question saying anything about an official having decided on anything. The answer cover *your interpretation* of the question, which may or may not be what was intended in the question. Regardless of what was intended with the question, the additional information I suggest adding would make it a better answer.

Comment: @kasperd The judge can not rule on what a player knows, only on what the judge believes. A question about a judge's ruling on what a player knows or believes to have done does not make sense. It only makes sense to interpret the question in the way I have, what happens if the judge believes that cheating has occured. OP clearly did not ask about the process of how a judge arrives at his opinion, only how he responds if he has a certain opinion, i.e. cheating has occured.

Comment: @Hackworth It is not reasonable to assume that the question was asked with all of the information needed to answer it. Generally, when a question is missing information, you have two options: address both possibilities in your answer, or ask the OP to clarify. I've gone ahead and asked the OP to clarify, since you don't seem willing to address the possible interpretation that kasperd brought up. I honestly think it would improve your answer even if that isn't what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Rainbolt thanks for asking. I don't get notifcations for comments on answers so I didn't know this discussion was even here. I hope it's all clear now for everyone

Comment: `The player must be attempting to gain advantage from his or her action.` - so doing it "for giggles" is not technically cheating? Interesting.